# Maven 1.x: Debug a single test

Tags: maven

To the elder maven users:

I have a legacy project with Maven 1.x.

I miss -Dtest=... and -Dmaven.surefire.debug ...

How can I achieve that with maven 1.x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See instructions on MAVEN_OPTS here:

http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/reference/command-line.html

(simply configure debug mode for the jvm. Note that test should not be forked then ...)

instead of `-Dtest=...` use `-Dtestcase=...`